# Media Url not resolving properly

Tags: python, django, url, media-url

I have the media url and media root as follows.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
```

my urls.py is

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am accessing it in the template as follows:

```
<img class="hl" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}prop/image0.png" /></a>
```

The url replaced when rendered is correct, which is `/media/prop/image0.png`.

But it says the media location is not found.

Comment: So, what have you configured to serve files at MEDIA_URL?

Comment: It was not properly creating media_root. So replaced it with absolute path. Its working fine now.

Comment: The MEDIA_ROOT variable was not able to get the absolute path which was causing the problem. I have corrected it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use staticfile for this purpose, because you are using a specific image and not something that will be uploaded in the future.

If you decide to use static files, put the image in your static folder and then use this:

```
 <img src="{% static 'image0.png' %}" style="">
```

Don't forget to load your staticfiles:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

By the way, for future, if you wanted to use media files in your templates you have to do it like this:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" class="h1">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The files are uploaded by user so using static is not possible. I found the problem with my settings.py. The MEDIA_ROOT variable was not able to get the absolute path which was causing the problem. I have corrected it and it works fine.